# Android - Reading XML issues

Tags: java, android

I've got an app that consumes a .NET web service which returns an XML string of data.  I'm trying to read this XML and insert it into the local SQLite DB but I'm having some trouble.  Here's a sample of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<string xmlns="RemoteWebService"><OpenIssues> <Table> <IssueID>15351</IssueID>   <IssueSummary>Computer keeps crashing. This continues to be a problem</IssueSummary> <LocationName>West Side</LocationName> <Status>WIP</Status> <CustomerID>89755</CustomerID> <CustomerName>West Side Computers</CustomerName> <CustomerShortName>WSC</CustomerShortName> <Notes /> <STATUS1>Work In Progress</STATUS1> <SubmittedBy>WSC - Tom Johns</SubmittedBy> <EQ_Replaced>true</EQ_Replaced></Table> </OpenIssues></string>
```

Using DOM, I'm trying to parse the results like so:

```
private void GetLatestData(String response) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));

    //Normalize the document.
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    //Get Root Node.
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Table");
    Node node = nodeList.item(0);

    //Get Child Nodes.
    for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){
        IssueInfo issue = new IssueInfo();
        Node tempNode = node.getChildNodes().item(i);

        if(tempNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("IssueID")){
            issue.setIssueNumber(Long.parseLong(tempNode.getTextContent()));
        }

        if(tempNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("IssueSummary")){
            issue.setIssueNumber(Long.parseLong(tempNode.getTextContent()));
        }               

        if(issue.getIssueNumber() > 0 && issue.getIssueSummary() != null){
            creator = new IssueInfoCreator(this, DBVersion);
            creator.open();
            creator.InsertIssue(issue.getIssueNumber(), DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()), issue.getIssueSummary());
            creator.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it through the debugger, it gets "IssueID" just fine but how can I get it to pickup the next node "IssueSummary" right after that so I can insert the data at once?  It seems like I need another loop somewhere, just not too sure where though.

Comment: Is it specific to Android?  That is, do you get the same error running the code as plain old Java in your IDE?   At first glance there doesn't seem to be a reason you can't access 'IssueSummary' the same way you grab 'IssueID'.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Android development but I'm developing this app with Eclipse and when I debug it, it's as an Android App.  Not sure how to run it as a Java app though.

Comment: It is DOM parsing irrespective Java/Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the resolution to this with the help of my coworker and some digging around.  It should be noted that we changed the WebService that returned a string from DataSet.GetXml() to an XmlDocument.InnerXml.  This removed the spaces in between the nodes and then we were able to move forward from there.  Here's the final code we used:

```
public void GetLatestData(SoapPrimitive xml)throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    //get the factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    //Using factory get an instance of document builder
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc;

    //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml.toString()));
    doc = db.parse(is);

   //Clear out Issues table first.
   creator = new IssueInfoCreator(this, DBVersion);
   creator.open();
   creator.ClearIssueTable();
   creator.close();

   NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Table");

   for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
       IssueInfo issue = new IssueInfo();

       Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);

       issue.setIssueNumber(Long.parseLong(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "IssueID")));
       issue.setIssueSummary(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "IssueSummary"));
       issue.setDateReceived(DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());

       if(issue.getIssueNumber() > 0 && issue.getIssueSummary() != null){
           creator = new IssueInfoCreator(this, DBVersion);
           creator.open();
           creator.InsertIssue(issue.getIssueNumber(), issue.getDateReceived(), issue.getIssueSummary());
           creator.close();
       }
   }
}
```

And here is the getValue method of the XMLfuntions class:

```
public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
    return XMLfunctions.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}

 public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node kid;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return kid.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }
```

Definately not taking credit for this, I found it here:
[Programmer XR](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/) and modified it to my needs.

Hopefully this will help other people out!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple DOM traversing issue.

If you can guarantee the next node is the summary, you could try using the [getNextSibling()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNextSibling%28%29) method for nodes

I modified your code so I could call it without using your classes. This is the code I used:

```
private static void GetLatestData(String response) {
    try{
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                /* the following 2 lines help you eliminate whitespace
                   from your xml DOM tree */
        dbf.setValidating(true);
        dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response)));

        //Normalize the document.
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        //Get Root Node.
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Table");
        Node node = nodeList.item(0);
        long issueNumber;
        String summary;

        //Get Child Nodes.
        for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){

            Node tempNode = node.getChildNodes().item(i);


            if(tempNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("IssueID")){
                issueNumber = (Long.parseLong(tempNode.getTextContent()));
                Node summaryNode = tempNode.getNextSibling();

                summary = summaryNode.getTextContent();
                System.out.println(String.format("Issue # %d, Summary: %s" , issueNumber,summary));
            }
        }


    }catch(Exception exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

and I call it like this:

```
GetLatestData("<OpenIssues> " +
"<Table> " +
    "<IssueID>15351</IssueID>" + 
    "<IssueSummary>Computer keeps crashing. This continues to be a problem</IssueSummary> " +
    "<Notes />" +
"</Table></OpenIssues> ");
```

from a simple Java class. It's working all right for me, at least. It prints out:

```
Issue # 15351, Summary: Computer keeps crashing. This continues to be a problem
```

Comment: yes, I tried that.  I created another Node variable and set it just after the issue.setIssueNumber statment, then used that new node to get IssueSummary but it doesn't pick it up.

Comment: Sorry, was in a meeting....I tried you code but didn't get the same results.  IssueID printed but nothing for IssueSummary.  So I had a look at my xml again and looks like I posted the wrong xml. I've edited my post above with the new one.  It's not all that different, in fact, the two fields I'm looking for are still 1 & 2 so it should still work, right?  The only thing I can think of is if the formatting is off?

Comment: You're exactly right. If I take the xml code as is, I get an empty summary as well (the node's next sibling is "  "). If I use the expression tempNode.getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getTextContent(), however, I get the right result. I guess that's why I asked if you could guarantee that the nodes would sit right next to each other.

Comment: So it comes down to the xml format then....ugh.  That's a web service we've written in .NET and all it does is take a DataSet and return the xml --> return ds.GetXml();  which is a string btw.  so .NET must be putting the extra space in between each node for whatever reason.

Comment: Well there definately seems to be something wrong with either the GetXml() method of the .NET DataSet or I'm doing something wrong (which is probably the case)...but if I run my web service and put a debug on the return statement, then look at the string it's returning, it's formatted correctly.  However, if I call the web service from my browser and look take the results, put them in a text file and try to open that as an XML, it doesn't open at all.  So some formatting is being left out somewhere.

Comment: I looked into it, and I found a way to make your parser eliminate whitespace. HOWEVER, it will try to validate your xml result. In my implementation, for instance, it prints a couple of parsing errors to the console.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it futher.  I'm pretty stumped here cause the XML being generated is straight from a .NET web service and I can't figure out why it's putting those spaces in there.  I even tried to put the xml in a string, replace the space (response.replace("> <", "><")) but it still didn't work.  Is there a chance the DOM is not parsing it correctly?

Comment: Well, you have to understand the DOM philosophy: it takes every element and makes it part of its tree. So, strictly speaking it's parsing the XML hyper-correctly. I looked at my own code and I return my results as an array of objects (using SOAP). Wouldn't that be a better way to handle this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7505/discussion-between-robert-and-digcamara)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you may need to do.

```
Node node = nodeList.item(0);
```

Returns

```
 <Table> 
        <IssueID>15351</IssueID> 
        <IssueSummary>Computer keeps crashing. This continues to be a problem</IssueSummary>
        <Notes />
  </Table> 

node.getChildNodes().getLength();
```

Returns 3.

```
  IssueInfo issue = new IssueInfo();
```

// Go through each child and find out node name and populate it.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){

        Node tempNode = node.getChildNodes().item(i);

        if(tempNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("IssueID")){
            issue.setIssueNumber(Long.parseLong(tempNode.getTextContent()));
        }

        if(tempNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("IssueSummary")){
            issue.setIssueNumber(Long.parseLong(tempNode.getTextContent()));
        }               


    }
```

Move if logic out of the loop.

```
if(issue.getIssueNumber() > 0 && issue.getIssueSummary() != null){
            creator = new IssueInfoCreator(this, DBVersion);
            creator.open();
            creator.InsertIssue(issue.getIssueNumber(), DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()), issue.getIssueSummary());
            creator.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

*smacks forehead*

`issue` will never have more than one value set, as it's created anew for each child node.

Just swap the two lines to create `issue` only once:

```
IssueInfo issue = new IssueInfo();
for(int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++){
   ...
```

You should probably move the final `if` outside the `for` too, so it's not executed more than once.

AND you'll need to actually set the summary in the second `if` not.  You're setting the 'issue number' twice.